# Adding multiple author

Tags: author-number

I am preparing my proposal I want to add multiple authors like this in the same line!

Submitted by XYZ... Guidance by XYZ and Members of committee XYZ all are in the same line! Please refer to the below image, How I can do this?

[image: Actual results I want]

Code are below,

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\author {\textbf{Submitted by} \\ \textit{Zalavadiya Sagarkumar Anilbhai}  \\
\hfill \\ 
\textbf{Under the guidance of} \\ 
\textit{Dr. Ali Akbari-Fakhrabadi}} \\

\affil {Faculty Of Mechanical Engineering, University Of Chile, Santiago Chile}

\flushbottom

\begin{document}
\maketitle \section {Introduction}
```

[image: What i am getting]

Comment: This can be done with a simple `tabular` environment. Did you try?

Comment: Yes sir I did it but the second one goes to the first page! Above the title! Its strange To look at my code I am sharing my overleaf template https://www.overleaf.com/6852897359hsjbxznywnyw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand the meaning of those `...`, `2` and `3` in your picture. So you will probably need to modify the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\author{%
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
      Roger Black    & ...  & Martin White      \\
    Black Department & ...  & White Departement \\
      Black School   & ...  & White School      \\
      email@black    & ...  & email@white
  \end{tabular}
}
\title{The Title}

\begin{document} 

\maketitle

\section {Introduction}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Sir, I added it according to your guidance but everything is not aligned vertically same! How I can be aligned it vertically same so it looks nicer?

Comment: Sorry, but which picture do you want to reproduce? The first one or the second one? To create a new line simply use `\\`. I do not have an Overleaf account!

Comment: One moment sir, I am sending you an overleaf link where you can noticed it https://www.overleaf.com/6852897359hsjbxznywnyw